# Convert enum type from Rust to Java

Tags: java, enums, rust

I have this source code for declaring `enum` in Rust, but I don't' understand it. What is the equivalent of it in Java?

```
pub enum BoxType<'a> {
    BlockNode(&'a StyledNode<'a>),
    InlineNode(&'a StyledNode<'a>),
    AnonymousBlock,
}
```

where: `BlockNode` and `InlineNode` are classes.

**Edit**
In the scope of the answer provided by :  ***Ionuț G. Stan***, how to use the code proposed by him to have the functionality of the following code.

```
match self.box_type {
    BlockNode(node) => node,
    InlineNode(node) => node,
    AnonymousBlock => panic!("Anonymous block box has no style node")
}
```

Comment: Note that there is *no line-for-line equivalent* in Java. This code uses lifetimes, a feature that Java doesn't need because it is a garbage-collected language.

Comment: The other problem is in fact that enums in Java are, well, enums (a collection of named constants), while enums in Rust are really tagged unions or, alternatively, algebraic data types. While tagged unions can represent plain enums easily, the converse is not true. In Java-like languages ADTs are usually modeled with class hierarchies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest equivalent is not an enum, but a class hierarchy and a visitor (to mimic the pattern matching part found in Rust):

```
public interface BoxType {
  public <R> R accept(BoxTypeVisitor<R> visitor);
}

public class BlockNode implements BoxType {
  public final StyledNode styledNode;

  public BlockNode(StyledNode styledNode) {
    this.styledNode = styledNode;
  }

  @Override
  public <R> R accept(BoxTypeVisitor<R> visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }
}

public class InlineNode implements BoxType {
  public final StyledNode styledNode;

  public InlineNode(StyledNode styledNode) {
    this.styledNode = styledNode;
  }

  @Override
  public <R> R accept(BoxTypeVisitor<R> visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }
}

public class AnonymousBlock implements BoxType {
  @Override
  public <R> R accept(BoxTypeVisitor<R> visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }
}

public interface BoxTypeVisitor<R> {
  public R visit(BlockNode box);
  public R visit(InlineNode box);
  public R visit(AnonymousBlock box);
}
```

As @Shepmaster said in a comment, note that there's no equivalent for the `'a` part. That's a Rust feature that Java doesn't need, because Java always uses GC.

#### UPDATE

How to port the pattern matching part. Use the provided visitor interface:

```
StyledNode styledNode = boxType.accept(new BoxTypeVisitor<StyledNode> {
  @Override
  public StyledNode visit(BlockNode box) {
    return box.styledNode;
  }

  @Override
  public StyledNode visit(InlineNode box) {
    return box.styledNode;
  }

  @Override
  public StyledNode visit(AnonymousBlock box) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Anonymous block box has no style node");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you , I have update the question with new small requirement. could you help me please ?

Comment: @lonut Awesome, last thing, to learn more about these concepts in Java. what should I study ?

Comment: @Adham I don't have a single resource to point you to, sorry. In general, learn functional programming. That will challenge some of your current beliefs/skills. You'll start to see new patterns and distill new knowledge.

Comment: @lonut what is the meaning of <R> T  ?

Comment: @Adham sorry, that should have been `<R> R` and it represents the **r**esult accumulated/produced by the visitor.